# Asp Radiobutton error

Tags: c#, asp.net, databinder

I would like the Id correspond to the data in the dataitem so that I know on which radiobutton the user clicked: I write:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdFlight") %> " runat="server" GroupName="Flights" />
```

But I get error of parser: the format of the tag is not correct.
Any hint please?

Comment: Use single quotes if you're using `Eval` in control attribute: `<asp:RadioButton ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdFlight") %>' runat="server" GroupName="Flights" />`

Comment: I tired that but I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML Input Radio instead of ASP.net Radio.
and write jquery function what you want.

```
<input type="radio" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "blog_id") %> "/>
```

Comment: And what if OP wants to check thee checked state in code behind?

Comment: but you dont need to to this at all..put simply asp.net radio button with normal ID="chkStatus" and write code behind . RadioButton chkdel = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("chkStatus") in repeater items.